# Hadoop Streaming Python Job - Subprocess failed with code 1

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to deploy an algorithm on a Hadoop cluster, written in Python, using the Hadoop Streaming functionality. When I try to execute it "locally", using the following syntax

```
cat poi/* | ./mapper_paths.py | ./combiner_paths.py | ./reducer_paths.py
```

it works like a charm, but when I try to deploy it on the cluster using the syntax

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.2.jar -input /poi -output /poi_outXXX -combiner "/root/combiner_paths.py" -mapper "/root/mapper_paths.py" -reducer "/root/reducer_paths.py"
```

it fails saying

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1

([here](https://pastebin.com/3Y6H0jDM) is the full log)

As now, I don't have access to the Python error logs, maybe due to how the cluster was deployed (I used [this](https://github.com/kiwenlau/hadoop-cluster-docker) Docker container), so I can't understand where the error exactly is.

These are the scripts: [Mapper](https://pastebin.com/80zVDP0k) | [Combiner](https://pastebin.com/Ez79M85p) | [Reducer](https://pastebin.com/KG4k1CBW)

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Please include the code and errors in the question itself